# Create membership number for existing/new users

Tags: customization, user-meta

I have a membership site with 4000+ users currently on it.

I am needing to give both new/existing users an automatic ID number.

its very similar to this: [Create Unique ID for user](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65738/create-unique-id-for-user)

However, this only works for new users, I need it to work for the current users too. So for instance, user id 3421 would get membership number 3421.

This is what I have so far: (pretty much all from above link)

```
function fb_add_custom_user_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
        <h3><?php _e('Extra Profile Information', 'Avada'); ?></h3>
            <table class="form-table">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <label for="memnumber"><?php _e('Membership Number', 'Avada'); ?>
                        </label>
                    </th>
                    <td>
                    <input type="text" name="memnumber" id="memnumber" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'memnumber', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <?php }

    function fb_save_custom_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
            return FALSE;
        update_usermeta( $user_id, 'memnumber', $_POST['memnumber'] );
    }
    add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'fb_add_custom_user_profile_fields' );
    add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'fb_add_custom_user_profile_fields' );
    add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'fb_save_custom_user_profile_fields' );
    add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'fb_save_custom_user_profile_fields' );




    add_action( 'user_register', 'assignuserid');

    function assignuserid($user_id) {
    global $wpdb;
    $latestid=$wpdb->get_var("SELECT meta_value from $wpdb->usermeta where meta_key='memnumber' order by meta_value DESC limit 1;");
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'memnumber', $latestid +1 );
}
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Wonder why it has to be a counting number instead of eg random string https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php. Custom table would preserve the values even if user was deleted. Your setup could in theory give a new user same memberid of a newly deleted member.

Comment: if you're using the user ID then that wouldn't be an issue and you wouldn't need to do this for existing or new members as they already have user IDs

Comment: Hi, I know they have ID's I just need their ID printed with a prefix [prefix4321] in the membership number within the user profile field

Comment: @birgire it needs to be counting as its a membership number that is being printed to a membership certificate.  Ideally needs to be their id with a prefix.

Comment: The problem with user ids is that they might not survive a migration just like post ids and change.

Comment: @birgire yeah that i part of the problem, I need it to be safe.  would there be a way to use the above link you shared but to never get the same random number twice?

Comment: The first question is if you want to alliow the reuse of member id of a deleted member or not. If allowed then look into eg hashing of unique usernames if you trust they will never change. If not allowed use eg random strings that could be checked for duplication before using, if needed (could be made though with very low probability of collision) and stored if member is deleted. That storing might need consideration though regarding gdpr and if such data need to be made anonymous for a deleted member.

Comment: @birgire the reason id ideally do it with id's is that the prefix will make it not matter if someone is deleted as it will change monthly.

Comment: do you want the prefix to be the same for all users?

Comment: @Himad yes I do.