# Create Unique and Customized User ID for Website Members in WordPress

Tags: plugin-development, custom-field, users, user-registration, user-meta

I want a Feature which can allow **Custom User ID** creation at Registration on WordPress.

This will be different from the User ID that WordPress creates at Registration.

This one is something that is **Custom Created** and **Custom determined** by Site Admin.

It will have a **Prefix** already determined by Admin, and the numbering system would also be pre-determined by Admin as well.

It could/should be treated as a **Custom Post Type** called "**Unique User ID**"that will be on the WordPress Dashboard Menu-- just like other plugins that we install. And it should have a **Shortcode** that can allow it to be displayed anywhere on Posts, Pages, and Widget areas in WordPress.

This Custom ID Feature will have the following Parameters:

1.) **ID TITLE**: This is the Name that Admin will call the **Custom ID**. And Admin should be able to create **Multiple Types** of Custom IDs according to User Type and User Role.

2.) **ID PREFIX**: A Prefix that will appear, separated by Comma, Dash, Pipe, or any other separator.

3.) **NUMBER FORMAT**: This is the Format in which the Numbers are applied. It can be numeric, starting from 1 and upwards. Or Admin can set it to have leading Zeros like “**000**” before the counting starts.

4.) **BATCH NUMBER RANGE**: This is the Number of Users that will form a Batch, before they are split into a new batch.

This range can be 1 to **1,000**(One Thousand), **10,000**(Ten Thousand) and whatever else the Admin decides.

5.)**BATCH ID TYPE**: This is the Grouping of Users into Batches, and the Type of Data Type used in this Grouping.

It could be--A to Z, Alphanumeric, Symbol, or Text.

6.) **OUTPUT**: When these are now pre-determined by Admin, and a User Registers on the website, a **Custom User ID** should be automatically generated during User Registration, and should be added to the WordPress Dashboard Menu, as “**User ID**” or whatever Admin has already pre-named it, as seen [here](https://prnt.sc/o07lm-UVtkFa)

So in this Case, as seen from the Image above, Admin has called the Custom ID “**Tag Number**“.

He has used the Prefix “**SP**“.

He has used **Number Format** with two leading Zeros “**00**“, and we can see that the current User is Number 19.

The User’s **Batch Number** is 1, where **Batch Number** is represented by “**BN**“.

I want to believe that by now, you understand what I am talking about?

So I am now asking if anyone knows of any WordPress plugin, or PHP Code Snippets that can do that for me?

I am following this [Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65738/create-unique-id-for-user) but I've not been able to convert it to my good use. Anyone here that can help?

Regards.