# Unique User Account Number + Displayed Via Shortcode

Tags: customization, users, user-meta

I've seen a couple articles on creating unique account numbers for users:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693209/create-unique-account-number-for-every-user-that-registers-to-the-system-using-w

[What is the fastest way to generate a unique id number when registering a user](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8912/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-generate-a-unique-id-number-when-registering-a-user)

I'm trying to see if someone could actually explain how it's actually done step by step. I'm not a seasoned developer, but I do have knowledge of accessing / creating / modifying code via ftp and dreamweaver.

**Here's what I'm looking to do:**
Create a unique account number (10 digits, 000-00-00000) for each user who signs up (including existing users), and have a way to see it on the backend, and display their specific account number via shortcode.